# QT QButtonGroup.checkedId() returns only one checked button

Tags: python, qt

I created a `QButtonGroup` (there might be unused artefacts in the code. Please ignore them). I would like to retrieve the Id of all checked radio buttons. However, the `QButtonGroup.checkedId()` does return only one button at a time.

Is it possible to retrieve a list of all checked RadioButtons ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout,\
                            QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QSplitter, QFrame, QTextEdit, QFileDialog, QGroupBox,\
                            QButtonGroup, QLabel, QRadioButton


class MyRadioButtonGroup(QWidget):
    """
    creates radio buttons from a list
    """
    def __init__(self, label, instructions, name_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.title_label = QLabel(label)
        self.name_list = name_list

        # create the widget
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.group_box = QGroupBox(instructions)
        self.button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.setExclusive(False)

        # create the buttons
        self.button_list = [QRadioButton(item) for item in self.name_list]

        self.button_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for i, button in enumerate(self.button_list):
            self.button_layout.addWidget(button)
            self.button_group.addButton(button)
            self.button_group.setId(button, i)

        self.group_box.setLayout(self.button_layout)

        # create the main layout
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.title_label)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.group_box)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # method for getting the state of the buttons

    def get_states(self):
        states = self.button_group.checkedId()
        return states

class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    """ This creates the main Window and configures its look
    """
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initializes the class with standard parameters
        '''
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Data Analysis App'

        # start at top left corner of the screen
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0

        # set the window height and width
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 780

        # set the styles of fonts etc.
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 16pt')

        # call the makeUI method
        self.makeUI()

    def makeUI(self):
        # set window geometry
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # generate the tab layout
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        # apparently we have to call the show method in order to show it
        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    """
    Initializes the tab layout
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # initialize the tab screens
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()

        # add the tab screens to the tab widget
        self.tabs.resize(600, 600)

        # make the layout of the tabs
        self.make_tab1()

        # initialize the tabs
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def make_tab1(self):
        """Style of tab 1 is created here"""

        '''Defines master layout of tab1'''
        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab1.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        '''Button Section'''

        # converts the data into excel and pandas dataframe
        btn_test = QPushButton('Test')
        btn_test.clicked.connect(self.test)

        name_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
        self.radio_buttons = MyRadioButtonGroup('TEST', 'Check more than one', name_list)

        '''Page layout section '''

        tab1.layout.addWidget(btn_test)
        tab1.layout.addWidget(self.radio_buttons)
        tab1.setLayout(tab1.layout)
        self.tabs.addTab(tab1, 'Test Radio Buttons')

    ''' Methods section
    '''
    def test(self):
        print(self.radio_buttons.get_states())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ This code block is always the same and makes sure that e.g. STRG+C kills the window etc.
    """
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just retrieve them with a list comprehension:

```
def test(self):
    print([i for i, button in enumerate(self.radio_buttons.button_group.buttons()) if button.isChecked()])
```

Comment: You and eyllanesc are saving my weekend.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: I was just about to find the same solution. Nice to see that I am getting it slowly